# How to manage foreign keys with Kettle/Spoon?

Tags: data-warehouse, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm filling my data warehouse's table (MySQL) after some transformations with spoon. However, my dimension table is filled and I've to fill my fact table from a CSV file. So, when I try doing it, kettle warn me ***there are some records that violate foreign key constraint*** and the transformation is aborted. This is caused because not all foreign keys in my CSV appear in my dimension tables. How can I control if a foreign key is present in the dimension table which refers by kettle?

Comment: you need to stage the data in another table first and then insert only records into the table that have a relationship with your dimension table, or create extra dimensions for fact data that are missing. - this is referential integrity being enforced so it is expected behaviour

Comment: Foreign keys feature already impelemented in database. Much easier to use it. Load data in tables then implement merging logic on database level